# PHP explode() puts everything into first array element

Tags: php, arrays, file, fopen, explode

The PHP `explode()` function puts everything into the first array variable. I have followed the example at: [explode](http://php.net/EXPLODE)

The file contains the following string:

`My CV_98KB_PDF(Adobe Reader)_YES - Use this form: Contact Form_/docs/CV.pdf`

I want it to split the string read from the file into separate array elements, yet it splits them into only the first.

```
$doclist = "./docs/documentlist.txt";
$filestr = readfile($doclist);
$docProp = explode("_", $filestr);

echo $docProp[0];
echo $docProp[1];
```

`$docProp[0]` contains the full string instead of `My CV`. Why does it do that?

Kind Regards.

Comment: I expect it to put everything into an array - so `$docProp[0] = My CV`, `$docProp[1] = 98KB` and so on.

Comment: kindly show what is written on the documentlist.txt just a sample

Comment: Did you mean to use `file_get_contents()` instead?

Answer (score 2):

[readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) outputs file to browser and returns number of bytes, so what you saw on page is result of `readfile()`, not `echo $docProp[0];`. What you need to do is to use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$doclist = "./docs/documentlist.txt";
$filestr = file_get_contents($doclist);
$docProp = explode("_", $filestr);

echo $docProp[0];
echo $docProp[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this:

```
$doclist = "./docs/documentlist.txt";
$docfile = fopen($doclist, "r") or die("file error!");

while (!feof($docfile)) {

    $docProp = explode('_', fgets($docfile));

};
fclose($docfile);
```

Instead of using `readfile()` I have used `fopen`, `feof` and `fgets` in order to read the file and explode it.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your string consists of '/' so based on that we should explode

```
$doclist = "./docs/documentlist.txt";
$filestr = readfile($doclist);
$docProp = explode("/", $filestr);

echo $docProp[0];
echo $docProp[1];
```